# Trying to Create a Monitor

Tags: google-chrome, javascript, tampermonkey

I found this. How do I make it so when it finds the keyword, in this case "test", it stops reloading (I don't want an alert; just so the page simply stops reloading).

```
$(document).ready(function()

{

    var LookFor = "test"; // Change this to find a different string

    if($('body:contains("' + LookFor + '")').length > 0)
    {
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

Comment: So you want it to reload if "test" does *not* exist?

Comment: I want it to basically look for "test" by reloading, then when it finds it I wish the script to simply stop. So yeah. Could you help? Kinda new at this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do the opposite of what the function already does, you need to flip the [comparison operator](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) on the `if` statement.

That is "greater than":

```
if($('body:contains("' + LookFor + '")').length > 0)
```

must become "less than or equal to":

```
if($('body:contains("' + LookFor + '")').length <= 0)
```

The full script then becomes:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var LookFor = "test"; // Change this to find a different string

    if($('body:contains("' + LookFor + '")').length <= 0)
    {
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by " to do the opposite of what the function already does"

Comment: The script you posted will reload when it finds the word "test". You said you want it to *stop* reloading when it finds the word "test". That means you want to do the opposite of what the posted script does.